# Meta: Visual Studio Licensing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I'm not entirely sure this is the right place to ask this as this question is not purely programming related.

I know that it is possible to use a VS Express Version in a commercial environment to produce products. But since VS Express 2013 you need a mandatory MS Account to receive the license for VS Express.

My question would be if it is possible to use a shared or "virtual" account instead of a personalized one? So instead of giving the name of the developer the name of an intermediary would own the account.

Comment: Legal advice is off-topic here; *technically* it is possible. If it is desirable to share an MS Account with many more MS services automatically bound to it and being liable for any actions of an uncontrolled "community" possibly using those services besides the VS license is a different question.

Comment: So practically it would be advisable for every developer to create his own account? Would also make more sense for me.